# How can I work on both a web and a mobile project flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, web, mobile, flutter-web

I am working on an Flutter app for a client, this app included 2 things: A mobile app for the users and a web app for the "admin" panel. I have started by creating the web app which I have finished.
I am now working on the mobile app, but I have forgotten to add something on the website.
It is annoying for me to use `flutter config --enable-web` or the opposite each time I switch to the other project.

So, my question is: Is it possible to work (an emulate) on a Mobile project AND a Web project in the same time? (The two projects opened at the same time)

Comment: You can still run the mobile app in the dev channel. If that is not an option. Check flutter version manager a tool from the community members available [here](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm). It allows per project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the channel to `beta`
`flutter channel beta`

Comment: Not working for me, AndroidStudio don't show me the possibility to emulate on Chrome

Comment: First of all, run doctor command ```flutter doctor ``` , then check the connected devices by this command  ``` flutter devices ``` ,  then run ``` flutter run ```.
I recommend using Visual Studio code